# JavaScript com ajax, retorno de função. Porque não funciona?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Fiz um código **JavaScript** para habilitar alguns botões e inputs em um FORM, de acordo com a permissão do usuário, armazenado em uma SESSION. Tinha feito assim:

```
function showEditButtons() 
{
   if ( verUserPermissions(8) === true )
   {
      btnConfirma.style.display = 'inline';
      btnCancela.style.display = 'inline';
      btnEdita.style.display = 'none';
      $('input.form-control:text').attr("disabled", false);
   }
}

function verUserPermissions(nivel){
   $.ajax({
       url: './funcoes/processaMaxDescAcresc.php',
       type: 'POST',
       data: {'OP':'NIVEL', 'NIVEL_ESPERADO':nivel},
       cache: false,
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
       {
          var result = (data.nivel_permitido == '1');
          if ( ! result )
          {
             abreModaldeAviso('Falha', 'Usuário não autorizado a alterar estes valores.', 'alerta');
          }
          return result;

       },
       error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
       {
          var result = false;
          abreModaldeAviso('Falha', 'Erro ao obter dados do usuario.', 'alerta');
          return result;
       }
   });
};
```

A função **PHP** **./funcoes/processaMaxDescAcresc.php** retorna corretamente a verificação do nivel do usuário. Mas apesar de a função **verUserPermissions**, retornar true, não habilitava os botõe e inputs na função **showEditButtons**.

Se eu mover o código da função **showEditButtons** para dentro da outra função, neste caso eliminando a função **showEditButton**, ai funciona, fica assim:

```
function showEditButtons() {
   verUserPermissions(8);
}

function verUserPermissions(nivel){
   $.ajax({
      ...
      success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
      {
         var result = (data.nivel_permitido == '1');
         if ( ! result ){
            abreModaldeAviso('Falha', 'Usuário não autorizado a alterar estes valores.', 'alerta');
         } else {
            btnConfirma.style.display = 'inline';
            btnCancela.style.display = 'inline';
            btnEdita.style.display = 'none';
            $('input.form-control:text').attr("disabled", false);
         }
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
      {
         var result = false;
         abreModaldeAviso('Falha', 'Erro ao obter dados do usuario.', 'alerta');
         return result;
      }
   });
};
```

A minha dúvida é, porque não funciona? Não conheço muito de JavaScript e ajax, mas a meu ver, deveria funcionar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isto acontece devido a "racing conditions", uma vez que ajax é, por padrão, asincrono as chamadas de Ajax não param um script;
ou seja:

```
function showEditButtons() 
{
   if ( verUserPermissions(8) === true )**
   {
      btnConfirma.style.display = 'inline';
      btnCancela.style.display = 'inline';
      btnEdita.style.display = 'none';
      $('input.form-control:text').attr("disabled", false);
   }
}
```

`**` aqui nesta linha, o que isto vai fazer é: "chama-me a função Z e se ela retornar verdade, faz a festa". No entanto, a função Z tem uma chamada de Ajax que tem a função success e fail (traduzindo isto quer dizer "Vai ali buscar qualquer coisa e, quando voltares com a resposta, usa uma das funçoes".

Ora, aqui está um problema: "quando voltares com a resposta". Isto quer dizer que o `verUserPermissions()` não retorna true; Ele executa uma função que, depois de algum tempo, executa ainda outra função e essa sim - retorna true ou false.

O inverso acontece quando passas o codigo para a função que é chamada *depois* da resposta chegar.

Comment: Boa... muito bom saber, as vezes alguns detalhes de algumas linguagens acabam atrapalhando bastante.

Comment: `uma vez que ajax é, por defeito, asincrono` ?? defeito?

Comment: @DanielOmine foi tradução à letra, queria dizer `padrão`. Bem visto :)

Comment: traduzir "default" como "defeito" é algo muito distinto..

Comment: @DanielOmine acontece quando não traduzo o que penso, como "donar" em vez de "doar" (donate); é uma daquelas falhas parvas :)

Comment: entendo, mas nao tem nada a ver essas justificativas.